# Расположение образов SCCM

Tags: windows, сервер, windows-10

Всем привет

Имеется Windows Server 2016  установленным SCCM 2016.

На сервере SCCM необходимо организовать PXE Boot. Все настройки провёл,завёл pxelinux,но возникла проблема с образами,а именно на сервере с sccm довольно мало дискового пространства,и поэтому wim располагаются на файловом сервере. При добавлении образа в 13gb,который расположен на ФС,эти 13gb так же съедаются и на сервере с SCCM. Можно ли сделать так,чтобы SCCM не грузил образ в SCCMContentLib,а грузил их с файлового сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

День добрый

SCCM всегда будет загружать контент на указанную точку распространения (Distribution Point (DP))

Но вы можете добавлять/удалять DP

Т.е. Можно реализовать следующую схему:
- добавить новую DP c поддержкой PXE
- убедиться что весь необходимый контент залит на новый DP
- удалить старый DP.